# How to create custom grid in slick slider carousel?

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, slider, slick.js

How to create [such a grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5SSr.jpg) using the slick.js library? The slick has its own styles and conditions for displaying the carousel. I tried to make a similar grid using flex and displaying a carousel in 2 rows, but I seem to be doing something wrong. Apparently my knowledge is not enough. I am attaching the clean slider code.

```js
$('.posts-curousel').slick({
  rows: 2,
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
.posts-curousel .slick-list {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.posts-curousel .slick-slide {
    margin-left: 30px;
} 

.posts-curousel .posts-carusel-item {
    position: relative;
}

.posts-curousel .slick-dots {
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<div class="posts-curousel">
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: I can't create complete HTML and CSS for you but I have edited the Html and CSS part that can help you. Please follow the steps as shown below.**

Added `box-sizing` property for padding between columns. You need to learn box-model in CSS to understand this `box-sizing: border-box` property and added some more CSS down for creating your required html structure.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.posts-carousel .slick-list {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.posts-carousel .slick-slide {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.posts-carousel .posts-carousel-item {
  position: relative;
}

.posts-carousel .slick-dots {
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0px;
}

/*added my css*/
.slick-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-6 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}
```

Just add you html structure as shown below

```html
<div class="posts-carousel">
  <!-- ADDED NEW HTML STRUCTURE -->
  <div class="posts-carousel-item d-flex">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
            class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carousel-item d-flex">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
            class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carousel-item d-flex">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
            class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carousel-item d-flex">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
            class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carousel-item d-flex">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
            class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp"
                class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
            </a>
            <h4>heading</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Always keep all the scripts above body closing tag. -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.posts-carousel').slick({
    rows: 1,
    dots: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
</script>
```